# React D3 Linechart component implementation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I want to use the [react-d3-components](https://github.com/codesuki/react-d3-components) to display some data. I tried to do this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ChartState from './chart-state'
import LineChart from 'react-d3-components'

class ChartWidget extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
  super(...arguments)
  this.state = new ChartState()
}

render () {
  return (
    <Chart state={this.state} />
   )
  }
}

const Chart = observer (({ state, data }) => (
<div>
  <LineChart
      data={state.data}
      width={400}
      height={400}
      margin={{top: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 10}}/>
 </div>
))

export default ChartWidget
```

but this does not work and I get the error `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of`_class`.`

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add `export default Chart` to the end of your code?

Comment: @SventenHaaf Yes I did, still same issue :-(

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself:

```
import { LineChart } from 'react-d3-components'
```

was the solution!